# Symfony2 DomCrawler returns empty node list

Tags: symfony, xpath

I am trying to receive some information from XML using Symfony2 DomCrawler. For training I am using the following XML structure: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

I want to get each book title written into $crawler

This is my code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class ImportController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($publisher)
    {
        $books = array();
        $bookstore = <<<'XML'
            <bookstore>

                <book category="COOKING">
                    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
                    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
                    <year>2005</year>
                    <price>30.00</price>
                </book>

                <book category="CHILDREN">
                    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
                    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
                    <year>2005</year>
                    <price>29.99</price>
                </book>

                <book category="WEB">
                    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
                    <author>James McGovern</author>
                    <author>Per Bothner</author>
                    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
                    <author>James Linn</author>
                    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
                    <year>2003</year>
                    <price>49.99</price>
                </book>

                <book category="WEB">
                    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
                    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
                    <year>2003</year>
                    <price>39.95</price>
                </book>

            </bookstore>
            XML;
        //Crawl now
        $crawler = new Crawler($bookstore);            
        $crawler->filterXPath('/bookstore/book/title')->text();
        return $this->render('souncImportBundle:Import:index.html.twig', array('publisher' => $publisher, 'books' => $books, 'msg' => $bookstore, 'crawler' => $crawler));
    }
}
```

This returns the following exception:

> The current node list is empty.
>   500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Why doesn't it do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message but i think that in your case, you should specify which item book you want :

```
$crawler->filterXPath("/bookstore/book*[name() = 'book' and (position() = 1)]/title")->text();
```

you can use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector to create your Xpath filer.

you can also get element like this i guess :

```
$counter = $crawler->filter('bookstore > book')->count();
for ($i=1; $i < $counter; $i++)
{
echo $crawler->filter('bookstore > book:nth-child('.$i.') > title')->text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your HEREDOC notation. You need to have your second `XML` all the way up against the left wall of the document; there can't be any whitespace before the terminator on line that contains it. I know that that sounds bizarre and that it will mess up your indentation but it's been a known issue with PHP for a long time. So your code should read:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class ImportController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($publisher)
    {
        $books = array();
        $bookstore = <<<'XML'
            <bookstore>

                <book category="COOKING">
                    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
                    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
                    <year>2005</year>
                    <price>30.00</price>
                </book>

                <book category="CHILDREN">
                    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
                    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
                    <year>2005</year>
                    <price>29.99</price>
                </book>

                <book category="WEB">
                    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
                    <author>James McGovern</author>
                    <author>Per Bothner</author>
                    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
                    <author>James Linn</author>
                    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
                    <year>2003</year>
                    <price>49.99</price>
                </book>

                <book category="WEB">
                    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
                    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
                    <year>2003</year>
                    <price>39.95</price>
                </book>

            </bookstore>
XML;
        //Crawl now
        $crawler = new Crawler($bookstore);            
        $crawler->filterXPath('/bookstore/book/title')->text();
        return $this->render('souncImportBundle:Import:index.html.twig', array('publisher' => $publisher, 'books' => $books, 'msg' => $bookstore, 'crawler' => $crawler));
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll notice also that StackOverflow's code editor isn't able to highlight correctly when that syntax is used. Everything within the HEREDOC is highlighted incorrectly but the highlighting goes back to being correct after the semicolon following `XML`.